# Transfer all sms from gingerbread to laptop

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, sms, data-transfer

I want to transfer all my sms from my old phone HTC Explorer with Android OS, v2.3 (Gingerbread) to my laptop. How can i do it?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! You could start with checking solutions on [similar questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sms+data-transfer). If those don't solve your issue, please return and [edit] your post to let us know what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You Could Try [this application](https://www.phonecopy.com/en/phones/view/htc_explorer_a310e_(pico)). It works on HTC and android, ITcan sync Contacts and backup sms just like Samsung's PC suit.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is spam or legit, but could you add the steps needed to use this app for the objective?